# PHP variable inside a chart tag for fusionchart

Tags: php, javascript, xml, fusioncharts

I have this php code for creating a line chart, i have put the whole chart tag inside a PHP variable

```
$XMLNPK = "<chart formatNumberScale='0' showValues='1' decimals='0' shadowAlpha='40' bgColor='FFFFFF,99CCFF' labelDisplay='ROTATE' rotateValues='1' slantLabels='1' formatNumberScale='0' decimalPrecision='0' showvalues='1' animation='1' numdivlines='5' numVdivlines='0' caption='Plant Population Vs Yield - FCV' adjustDiv='0' yAxisMinValue='1900' yAxisMaxValue='2100' numDivLines='5'>";
```

What I wanted to do is to add this php variables which contains the max and min value of a field into the yAxisMinValue and yAxisMaxValue

```
<?php 
            $maxfcv = max($yieldfcv);
            $minfcv = min($yieldfcv);
```

?>

I tried this following code but it doesn't show the value:

```
...numVdivlines='0' caption='Plant Population Vs Yield - FCV' adjustDiv='0' yAxisMinValue='".$minfcv."' yAxisMaxValue='".$maxfcv."' numDivLines='5'>
```

Can anyone help me on this. Thank you in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure any of the chart's value is not beyond (greater than the max or lower than the min) the limits you are setting. If true, the chart does not crop the overflowing sections, rather it auto-calculates new min and max to make the line properly visible int he canvas.